# Pitfalls in doing GLMM or interpreting GLMM results

Tags: glmm

I know this is a general question, but it would benefit CVers to learn about
common pitfalls, things to consider and caveats on how to do rigorous GLMM modeling. 
Could those with experience on GLMMs share any insights they might have?

Comment: This is either more appropriate as a CW or it should be closed as too broad. If you've run into some specific questions based on practice, a more suitable question for this community would be based on specific context and motivation.

Comment: As stated, this question is unlikely to be of any help if you can't focus on specific issues. As the draft R-sig-mixed FAQ suggests, there are too many issues to fit into a single thread on Cross Validated. However, don't hesitate to ask specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

I came across [this link](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq) which addresses many issues in running GLMM models.